# Error code from `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt`

Tags: web3js, blockchain, javascript

I have code structure like this.

```
try {
    await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e);
}
```

When the `hash` is `123`, for example, an error is thrown. However in my browser devtools I can see that in the network response there is error code and error message. The error code appears to vanish in between. How can I get this error code?

P.S. The output of `console.log`s is like this:

```
Returned error: invalid 1st argument: transaction_hash value was not valid hexadecimal
undefined
Error: Returned error: invalid 1st argument: transaction_hash value was not valid hexadecimal
    at Object.ErrorResponse (web3.min.js:22:1)
    at eval (web3.min.js:22:1)
    at eval (web3.min.js:33:1)
```